# Ctrl-End doesn't bring me to the last cell

Tags: excel, vba

Ctrl-end key is supposed to bring me to the **bottom, right-most cell**. However, on several cases, it goes beyond that, meaning it goes hundreds of cells down, even if there are actually no data on those cells.

Can you advise a VBA script on how to clean-up those possibly invisible data that causes this? I'm pretty sure it doesn't work with a regular delete as despite doing that, it still behaves the same way.

Comment: When I get those, I delete the extra columns and rows and save. When I reopen, that 'bug' is fixed. Otherwise, I guess you could also copy/paste the useful information to a fresh new worksheet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This script will reset the last used row for any sheet that is active when it is run.

```
Sub Reset()

    Dim lngCount As Long

    lngCount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer as it addresses the problem without necessarily getting me to commit to a Save. I'm simply assigning F5 to this macro and problem really solved. Thank you.

Comment: I don't get it. It simply creates a number variable and assigns a value to it. It doesn't do anything to workbook itself.

Comment: It forces Excel to recalculate the last cell.  Try this test in a new workbook.  Enter numbers cells A1:A6, Select A1, press Ctrl+End, it will select cell A6.  press the delete key to delete the number in A6, Select A1, press Ctrl+End, Cell A6 is selected even though there is no data in it.  Run the macro.  Select A1, press Ctrl+End, it will now select cell A5, the last cell with data in it.

Comment: Apparently simply [accessing `ActiveSheet.UsedRange` resets the last cell](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2589-excel-reset-last-cell.html#a2). Though trying to do `Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet` followed by `ws.UsedRange` gives `Invalid use of property`, so assigning to a dummy variable seems to be required: `Dim dummy As Range: Set dummy = ws.UsedRange`

Comment: Doesn't work for me..

Answer (score 13):

Ctrl-End does take you to the bottom-right cell, it just uses different rules to what you'd expect in deciding what that cell should be. Just about any cell that's been referenced in any way will be included in the decision. It's annoying, but that's how Excel "works".

[Here's a description of how to address the problem](http://www.contextures.com/xlfaqApp.html#Unused).

To paraphrase:

1. Select the last cell that contains data in the worksheet
2. To delete any unused rows:

   - Move down one row from the last cell with data.
   - Hold the Ctrl and Shift keys, and press the Down Arrow key
   - Right-click in the selected cells, and, from the shortcut menu, choose Delete
   - Select Entire Row, click OK.
3. delete entire row
4. To delete any unused columns:

   - Move right one column from the last cell with data.
   - Hold the Ctrl and Shift keys, and press the Right Arrow key
   - Right-click in the selected cells, and, from the shortcut menu, choose Delete
   - Select Entire Column, click OK.
5. Save the file. Note: In older versions of Excel, you may have to Save, then close and re-open the file before the used range is reset.

Comment: The save is the important thing, as it is conterinctuitive

Comment: @momobo Yup, it works. I think it's the Save that sort of resets the grid. Thanks both.